# SwiftUI View does not disappear instantly after the transition animation ends

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, transition

I created an application with move transition, which sends a View up from below with SwiftUI. However, when View disappears, transition animation is over, but the View remains for about 1 second.

This is my code.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var animation: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            // This is the Button
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.spring(dampingFraction: 1, blendDuration: 0.5)) {
                    animation.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
            
            // This condition sends up the View
            if animation {
                SecondView()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[And this happened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vfaS.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to apply the animation directly to your button by using the animation modifier so your code may look like this:

```
Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                animation.toggle()
            }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        }
        .animation(.spring(dampingFraction: 1,    blendDuration: 0.5), value: animation)
        if animation {
            SecondView()
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. But animation is not applied to the Child View using this method.

Comment: you'll then wrap the button with withAnimation  like the edited version

Comment: I want to apply spring animation to transition of child view in which 'withAnimation' is involved. Not default animation.

Comment: you mean on the SecondView()?

Comment: Yes. The SecondView()

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Spacer()` from `SecondView()`, SwiftUI is having a hard time doing this transition with that spacer. Instead, be more explicit with the size of SecondView, change your SecondView code for this:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Remember to check this code on simulator since the preview is not reliable to test transitions.